# Looking for old satellite images

Tags: api, satellite

I'm looking to display satellite images of regions on a timeline starting from 2010, preferably updated regularly say every month or so. Are there apis that provide that for commercial use ?

Comment: you mean something like Google Timelapse ? https://earthengine.google.com/timelapse/ What resolution?

Comment: Yes, something I can download images from. For the resolution I don't need anything big, I just wanna see crop fields over time

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download images from 2010, you can go the Nasa [Earthdata](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/) portal. There you will find tons of Landsat images. And it looks as though there is a way to access some web services.

https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/GIBS+API+for+Developers

Answer (score 2):

[LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer) contains full collections of medium-resolution imagery dating back to 80’s.

- Sentinel-1 - archive since 2014
- Sentinel-2 - archive since 2015
- Landsat 4 - archive 1982-1993
- Landsat 5 - archive 1984-2013
- Landsat 7 - archive since 1999
- Landsat 8 - archive since 2013
- MODIS - archive since 2012

You mark the location and it shows you all available imagery from various active and past satellites. From there on, you can pick those you need and act depending on your purpose: view, run remote sensing analysis, download images.

I randomly chose Milan as search location in Landviewer, set cloudiness filter to minimum and found over 450 satellite images for it.

[**Here’s**](https://eos.com/landviewer/?anti&b=Red,Green,Blue&id=LT05_L1TP_193029_19840420_20171213_01_T1&lat=45.44917&lng=9.30576&s=Sentinel1&z=12) the oldest one, taken by Landsat 5 in April 1984:

[image]

And [**this**](https://eos.com/landviewer/?anti&b=Red,Green,Blue&id=S2B_tile_20181024_32TNR_0&lat=45.44917&lng=9.30576&s=Sentinel1&z=12) is a recent one from Sentinel-2:

[image]

One more thing to add: in case you are looking for old satellite images in order to perform multitemporal analysis - there’s this Landviewer feature called Time Series. It allows to build a graph that shows how a certain parameter performed over time.

All images used for calculation can be visualized and rendered on the map with a click. Quite useful if you need to visualize the dynamics of some parameter and identify patterns for current decision making or predicting possible result (e.g. crop yield).

Answer (score -1):

Google Earth Pro has a historical function that displays changes over time. For the time between 2010 and now, there may be 6 images. The interval lengths between image capture seem random and perhaps too long, but could be a start. Its fairly straight forward to capture images out of Google Earth and geo-reference based on known points.